# React-Native Error: Element type is invalid()

Tags: react-native

When I launch my app on iOS I get that error:
Element type is invalid: expected a string or class/function, but got: undefined. You likely to forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
Check the render method of LoginForm

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

const store = createStore(reducers);

class App extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
 const config = {
  apiKey: 'dawdawdas',
  authDomain: 'dasdasd',
  databaseURL: 'dasdasd',
  projectId: 'dasd',
  storageBucket: 'dsdasd',
  messagingSenderId: 'dasdasda'
  };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

render() {
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <LoginForm />
  </Provider>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

And LoginForm.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardSectiion, Input, Button } from './common';

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Card>
    <CardSectiion>
      <Input
        label="Email"
        placeholder="User@example.com"
      />
    </CardSectiion>

    <CardSectiion>
      <Input
        secureTextEntry
        label="Password"
        placeholder="Password"
      />
    </CardSectiion>

    <CardSectiion>
      <Button>
        Login
      </Button>
    </CardSectiion>
  </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm exporting the LoginForm class, but get this error.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { Card, CardSectiion, Input, Button } from './common';
```

The problem seems occured in this part.Check out that each component was exported correctly.

Comment: oh thanks! that was exactly the problem! I wrote CardSectiion instead of CardSection)

Comment: @НаурызАбдикадиров you could use editor plugin to avoid typos like this.